# Auto + static in-class constant initalization with meta-programming

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, static-members, auto

Consider the following simplified template meta-programming code that implements an `Angle` class that is internally storing the modulo 360 degrees reduced value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template<int N, int D>
struct Modulus
{
        static auto const value = N % D;
};

template<int N>
struct Angle
{
        static auto const value = Modulus<N, 360>::value; // ERROR
        //static int const value = Modulus<N, 360>::value;  // OK
        //static auto const value = N % 360;                // OK

        typedef Angle<value> type;
};

int main()
{
        std::cout << typeid(Angle<30>::type).name() << "\n";
        std::cout << typeid(Angle<390>::type).name() << "\n";

        return 0;
}
```

Output on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/4v7pg)

With Visual C++ 2010 Express, I can do `static auto const = Modulus<N, 360>::value`, but with MinGW gcc 4.7.2 ([Nuwen distro](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html)) or Ideone (gcc 4.5.1) I have to either explicitly denote the type as `static int const value = Modulus<N, 360>::value` or I have to use `auto` with the full modular expression as `static auto const value = N % 360;`.

**Question: Which compiler is correct acccording to the new C++11 Standard?**

Comment: Yes, in gcc 4.5.1 the support for C++11 is still very incomplete, you should check http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html to see which features are available in which version.

Comment: @hvd, incorrect. those must be declared constexpr.

Comment: @SegFault I also get these errors with MinGW 4.7

Comment: @hvd i dont have the spec handy. but a constexpr static data member is a static datamember too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is valid.  Visual C++ is right to accept it and gcc is wrong to reject it (for completeness, Clang 3.1 also accepts the code).  The specification states that (C++11 7.1.6.4[dcl.spec.auto]/4):

> The `auto` *type-specifier* can also be used...in declaring a static data member with a *brace-or-equal-initializer* that appears within the *member-specification* of a class definition.

Your `value` is a static data member.  It has a *brace-or-equal-initializer* (that is the `= Modulus<N, 360>::value` part of the declaration), and the initializer appears within the *member-specification* of the class definition (i.e., it's what mortals might call an "inline initializer").

Comment: +1 and accepted. Thanks a lot! What is the most appropriate way to file a bug report?

Comment: @rhalbersma:  GCC has [a Bugzilla database](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/).  I am not familiar with their bug reporting procedures, though.  I'd recommend searching first to see whether this has already been reported.